# How to get more PySide6 styles in pip virtual environment?

Tags: python, qt, pyside6, qt6, qstyle

I am making a program in PySide6 and have a pip venv setup, but this way [QStyleFactory.keys()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstylefactory.html#keys) shows only "Windows" and "Fusion" styles. Is there any way to get more themes, or set the style to the system's qt6 theme? I'm running on Arch and followed the [steps from the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications#QGtkStyle) for qt6 platform theme, but my program is using "Fusion" standard theme.